# No intervening numbers in input. Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, function-definition

**I am trying to figure the how to include into a while loop the following requirements "Numbers cannot be used in the middle of [an input]; they must come at the end [e.g. AAA222 is valid but not AAA22A]". The code passes all the requirements but this one! The hurdle is "CS44P2"! Perhaps I need to use a for loop instead?**

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

def is_valid(s):
    if len(s) < 2 or len(s) > 6:
        return False
    if s[0].isdigit() == True or s[1].isdigit() == True:
        return False
    

#“All vanity plates must start with at least two letters.”
#“… vanity plates may contain a maximum of 6 characters     
#(letters or numbers) and a minimum of 2 characters.”
    
    c = 0
    while c < len(s):
        if s[c].isalpha() == False:
            if s[c] == '0':
                return False
            else:
                break
        c += 1

#"Numbers cannot be used in the middle #of a plate; they must come at the end."
    
    if s.isalnum() == False:
        return False

#“No periods, spaces, or punctuation #marks are allowed.”
    return True

main()
```

Comment: Seems like a good opportunity to read up on regular expressions and how to use those.

Comment: Do you mean import regex? In the class I'm taking we have not covered that. I am assuming we must use code we have covered thus far.

Comment: `for` or `while` does not really make a difference here, but `for` is more convenient here, since you won't have to manually increase the counter. For the "no digits in the middle" check you should just loop over all the symbols. Remember when you saw the first number, and return False if you see a letter after that.